# Porque se genera el error: "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

Al parecer me sale un error al querer declarar v_idartista pero no se porque. Lo que me sale es ORA-06550: línea 11, columna 45:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "S" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:   ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or default like like2 like4 likec as between from using || multiset member submultiset
06550. 00000 -
"line %s, column %s:\n%s"

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    
DECLARE
    v_CantCDs NUMBER(5);
    v_cantCanc NUMBER(5);
    v_idartista artista.idartista%TYPE;
BEGIN
    V_IDARTISTA:='2000000-1ZY';
    
    --CANTIDAD DE CDS
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_CantCDs FROM CD WHERE idartista = v_idartista;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('La cantidad de cd's es:' || v_CantCDs);
END;
/
```

Comment: Estoy adivinando pero... `'La cantidad de cd's es:' || v_CantCDs`, no sé como sea en plsql, pero en sql estándar, las comillas simples determinan el inicio y final de una cadena. Supongo que debe ser `'...cd''s es...`.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que agregar 2 apóstrofes para poder usarlo dentro de una línea de texto. De lo contrario estarías cerrando el texto y se origina el error que ves.

```sql
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('La cantidad de cd''s es:' || v_CantCDs);
```